# Opera - linked script not loaded from localhost

Tags: https, url-rewriting, localhost, opera

When I rewrite HTML source of https page with Opera I got error:

**linked script not loaded** with `http://localhost:4444/index.js`.

When I use `http://mypage/index.js` everything goes right.

Putting any of links directly as address works just the same.

The most mysterious about this is, that it worked few hours ago and opera started to refuse `localhost` connection after computer restart.

I already tried to reinstall Opera and put `localhost` as trusted. No firewall active.

I just DONT UNDERSTAND :(

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers to be sure it's an Opera problem?

Comment: I can not edit source in other browsers. I need to edit linked script and then reload page with that script. I tried to do it in several other browsers, but no one did as opera.

Comment: It's a know problem where site specific settings for `localhost` host name are inconsistent (regardless of port number or protocol). I'd suggest deleting the `localhost` entry from the *Server Manager* and never save any setting for the `localhost` host name. Restart Opera if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

opera:config#Network|AllowCrossNetworkNavigation might help, but this is almost certainly the block for cross network communication.  It's a security feature.

Comment: Yea, I allready allowed it and aplication holds somehow :D I try not to touch it anymore and hope it will be working few months at least :D